# WebRTC bandwidth requirements

Tags: webrtc, bandwidth

Does anyone know what are WebRTC bandwidth minimal requirements?
I'm interested in what are the values with or without video and for different video resolutions. I'm especially interested in a two party conference, but if you know the values per party it's also good.

If you have actual metrics is nice, but also if you know how can I theoretically calculate this is also good.

Also, different browsers have different bandwidth requirements?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The bandwidth requirements are almost the same as the bandwidth requirement for [opus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_%28audio_format%29) and [vp8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP8). Real time audio typically has a bitrate of 40-200kbit/s. Video requires at least 200 kbit/s (500kbit/s if you want to see people's faces).

According to [webrtc-experiment](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/webrtcpedia/) the minimum bandwidth for opus is 6kbit/s and for vp8 100kbits/s. So in total that makes 106kbit/s but when you account for the overhead of the webrtc protocol stack and constantly varying network conditions I would guess that 200kbit/s is the minimum if one wants stable video and audio.

Chrome and Firefox both use opus and vp8 so the bandwidth requirements should be the same. Although I don't have any hard data to prove it.

You can see the current traffic generated by webrtc by going to chrome://webrtc-internals and inspecting all the charts.

Comment: Do you know if the webrtc-experiment refers to Chrome only or it is about other browsers as well?

Comment: opus and vp8 are separate not-connected to webrtc projects so the results in webrtc-experiments regarding these two technologies should be browser independent. I don't know about the rest of the results. I guess that they refers to both Chrome and Firefox. After all the two implementation share some code and the testing looks quite thorough.

Comment: why P2P video call need bandwidth for turn and stune server?? I think after connected, the turn and stune server no need to do any thing?

Answer (score 13):

For two-party conferences, 500 kbit/s for good conference-quality should be enough (per stream, so 1 Mbit/s load on a user's line). I'm in line with the other answer about that.

However, multi-party WebRTC bandwidth can be bottlenecked not just because of participants' Internet bandwidth, but also due to potential bandwidth limits of a TURN media relaying server, if you use one – ­which is needed where no P2P connections are possible due to difficult NAT setups. ([All the details here.](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/))

I attempted a rough calculation of how many users a TURN server can serve before maxing out its bandwidth:

- Let's say we have 100 Mbit/s server bandwidth in total (in + out), and we want at most 60 Mbit/s used up by WebRTC traffic.
- So for example when configuring the [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn) TURN server, we'd set input and output stream each to 30 Mbit/s (3,750,000 Byte/s, using `bps-capacity=3750000`).
- The output stream will experience the higher load, because given *n* participants, there will be *1* video input stream and *n-1* video output streams per participant for the TURN server to handle. Means the bottleneck will be the 30 Mbit/s combined output stream.
- In the worst case (where no STUN negotiated P2P connections at all are possible), this bandwidth will suffice for: 30 Mbit/s / 500 kbit/(s*stream) = 60 video streams.
- Given *n* participants, there will be *n-1* output streams per participant, which means a total of n * (n-1) = n^2 - n streams. Our max. 60 streams are then enough for: n^2 - n = 60 <=> n = 8.26 = ~8 participants ([calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20x%5E2%20-%20x%20%3D%2060)).

Not sure yet how accurate this is, though.